# Add char on specific place in filename for multiple files by batch

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I need to add a single char on a specific filename-position for multiple files in the same folder like this:

Before:

```
mySeries.s01e01.firstEpisodeTitle.mkv
mySeries.s01e02.secondEpisodeTitle.mkv
mySeries.s01e03.thirdEpisodeTitle.mkv
```

After:

```
mySeries.s01e001.firstEpisodeTitle.mkv
mySeries.s01e002.secondEpisodeTitle.mkv
mySeries.s01e003.thirdEpisodeTitle.mkv
```

I'm working on Windows and would like to know how to realize this by batch command.

Comment: Don't make it harder than it needs to be and use either PowerShell or one of the countless renaming tools. Just search for `.s01e` and replace it with `.s01e0`.

Comment: I definitely agree, but on the other hand, fixed-offset edits are something even cmd.exe batch scripts can handle. Iirc the syntax is `%var:begin:end%`?

Comment: Well I don't have much experience in PS, what would the command look like? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found out by myself:

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "oldText","newText" }
```